DllImport of win32 dll in mono project
I'm using .net core 8.0 and mono to open a remote session to a windows machine event log and read the logs.
My code is running on a linux machine. The problem is when I'm getting to the UnsafeNativeMethods class in mono,
there is a function
[DllImport(WEVTAPI, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[SecurityCritical]
internal static extern EventLogHandle EvtOpenSession(
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] EvtLoginClass loginClass,
                    ref EvtRpcLogin login,
                    int timeout,
                    int flags
                            );

when
internal const String WEVTAPI  = "wevtapi.dll";

and when this code run on the linux machine I get the following exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'wevtapi.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
Error loading shared library /app/wevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/wevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library wevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /app/libwevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/libwevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library libwevtapi.dll.so: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /app/wevtapi.dll: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/wevtapi.dll: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library wevtapi.dll: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /app/libwevtapi.dll: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.8/libwevtapi.dll: No such file or directory
Error loading shared library libwevtapi.dll: No such file or directory

I thought "mono" is supposed to run on linux, how can it be that it uses win32 dll with dll import?
Is there other way to run .netcore code on linux that can read event logs from a remote windows server?

Literally, the entire post is just one question, "what's the right way to read event logs from a Windows machine on Linux". .NET 8 alone won't be able to serve that because what you asked for is very Windows centric. But PowerShell remoting over SSH was designed for such scenarios, https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/security/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell So, probably you might call PowerShell from within your .NET 8 app and achieve the same.
